# Avatar Layering and Animating in Flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, animation, movieclip

So for my latest Flash project, I'm designing a game. The dimetric character can move in 8 directions. I've been given the spritesheets for the hats, hair styles, etc., that the player can wear.

The spritesheets contain the images for each direction, AND they contain four frames of animation (four per direction) for when the player is walking. This is basically the layout of the Spritesheet (and all of the files and "frames" are the same size, which makes things easier):

```
[IDLE]              [WALKING]                 
[S][SE][E][N][NW][W][S1][S2][S3][S4][SE1][SE2]...
```

My goal is to embed all of the items in a single file other than the main one. But I need to implement walking animation.

One thought I had is to set the main SWF's framerate to 7 FPS, then use an Event.ENTER_FRAME handler to alternate between the walking ones. Programmatically animating.

Another thought is to create SWFs for each item of clothing, then use motion tweening to move the spritesheet symbol over the stage.

What I'd really like it so avoid using Adobe Animate entirely. Even if there's an approach that requires the use of Flex, I'd take it if it meant saying goodbye to graphically-designing.

Comment: Look up blitting walk cycle. Blitting is copying pixels from a Sprite sheet and drawing them to a canvas. This can be done very quickly and completely programmatically.

Comment: By quickly I mean it is efficient for the computer to do. May involve learning some new methods but much of what you will need is already natively available to the flash player

Comment: Okay this was actually what I was finding out. So helpful, thank you.

Comment: Let me ask you, though: is it really CPU-efficient? There will be 30-50 sprites moving through the walk-cycles asynchronously. Not only is the tweening a bit concerning, but it's the constant re-drawing of bitmaps.

Comment: If it is done correctly it can be very efficient. I'm not the pro on the specifics but there are many tutes online.

Answer (score 0):

using flash builder (flex) does not mean that good bye graphic! there is a relationship between Adobe Flash and any As3 Ide like FlashBuilder or FlashDevelop.

exporting movieclips and everything in library with **.swc** format, and then importing it by the **IDE**, [**read this**](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/articles/animation_flash_fbuilder.html)

> My goal is to embed all of the items in a single file other than the
>   main one. But I need to implement walking animation.
>
> One thought I had is to set the main SWF's framerate to 7 FPS, then
>   use an Event.ENTER_FRAME handler to alternate between the walking
>   ones. Programmatically animating.

i dont undrestand! why **7 fps** and also why **Event.ENTER_FRAME**
there might be a character movieclip, whit above frames in its time line, well! to playing any animation (for particular direction) you have to call `mc.gotoAndPlay("walk_S");` then it will be played automatically, if you need lower frame rate, only select each frame by mouse pointer and then press [F5] in time line to insert a blank frame gape between keyframes.

as i said [before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40825081/5862335), you must use a **callback script** at the end frame of the  each loop animation like walk_s  walk_ne ...

also idle animations must be called like it:  `mc.gotoAndStop("idle_s");`

Comment: There are existing clients out there that I've decompiled and don't seem to do any of the things that you described. They use one frame in their entire application, and the characters still have animation. 7 FPS, by the way, because that's the transition speed between the game frames.

Comment: @Fuselight that single frame may contains a movieclip which has many other frames inside, also i'm ready to solve, feel free to posting me any FLA project that explains what you need in a better way, this answer will be updated according your need

Comment: I already checked for that, and that's not true either. There aren't any frames inside of any of the movie clips I've reviewed, and I've ensured that I look at all of the parent and children.

Comment: @NealDavis from the past to now, almost it was my wish to get born again in Europe or America just for their language, but the god did not get me that chance yet! XD . my beautiful language is like this **خیلی هم عالیه** *Persian* and they are so far. i'm glad for any improvements in valuable answers(they are not mine) i'll kiss your hands if you edit them if they are really incomprehensible. **http://pictub.club/image/WPowI** also one more thing i have to say, i'm really happy for meeting you in As3 Questions, here is really Quiet Horror in this category without you :D